# C# 64 bit WebP encoding library

Tags: image-processing

All the existing (Interop) C# libraries I've found wrap a 32 bit version of libwebp.dll

As a result, I (correctly) get an ImageFormatException when I try to use the wrapper from a 64 bit program... Unfortunately, I can't find a 64 bit version of libwebp.dll or a suitable wrapper...

Ideally, I'd like to see a managed code implementation. Does anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

My library [ImageProcessor](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/tree/6092da59e9aa4975e564002ef3c782a8f6bf3384/src/Plugins/ImageProcessor/ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP/Resources/Unmanaged) wraps both the 32 and 64 bit version as you can see at the link. A far as I'm aware there are no managed implementations available.

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment? Have I broken some sort of rule?

Comment: While I didn't downvote, I imagine it'll be because you haven't included your source code on github...

Comment: @Nathan Eh, It's all there? Thousands of lines of the stuff.

https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/6092da59e9aa4975e564002ef3c782a8f6bf3384/src/Plugins/ImageProcessor/ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP/Imaging/Formats/WebPFormat.cs

Comment: Ah, so it is - but you've linked direct to the binaries.

Comment: Dunno why folk would downvote that... maybe they tried it out and had a problem...?  Sorry, can't think of anything else.

Comment: No worries, just odd as all. I linked to the folder where both binaries are stored to demonstrate that the source code embedded both as a resource. It all works fine enough. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Se this project:

Is a wrapper for 32 and 64 bits webP

https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper